# How can I override a method in Javascript and apply it to the original object, not a child?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to override the `play()` method of the Audio object, but I don't want to do so just for a child object. I want to apply it to the standard Audio object.

The problem is I also want to use the original `play()` method. I've tried cloning the Audio object, making the changes, while calling the original Audio object's `play()` method and re-assigning back to the original Audio object. It doesn't work.

Ideas anyone? As an example, how could you add an `alert()` in the `play()` method while still calling the original play method?

plz. I need to do this because I have calling code generated by a tool that is calling new Audio. So it will be a super pain to constantly have to do a replace-all on this for the hundreds of code generations I'm doing.

Comment: Can we see the code you tried? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this could be done like this:

```
var playOriginal = Audio.prototype.play;
Audio.prototype.play = function(){
    playOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

But I'm not sure this will work for all browsers. Extending of native JS object is not recommended in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

```
Audio.prototype.play = ( function( old ) {
   var a=1, b=2, c=3; // your 'private' variables - if needed;
   return function() {
      console.log( a+b+c );// do something   
      return old.apply( this, arguments );// return 'original' results
   }
} )( Audio.prototype.play );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the original play method, then replace the play method with a new method that can call the original method whenever it wants to.

```
Audio.prototype.playOriginal = Audio.prototype.play;
Audio.prototype.play = function(){
    this.playOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
}
```